# Devise, Ruby on Rails, Change format of login details before authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We were using devise with an email, but we are now transitioning to a mobile login (user gives their mobile number) since this is the only info we need. Email would be good but not required.

I have got it working with mobile number authentication with:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :mobile ]
```

It works, if you enter the number exactly as entered. Though there are many ways people can enter in a number (vs email)

i.e

in the local format
0125551234

or international
27125551234

I actually normalize the mobile number when i store it in the DB, so would like to use the same normalization before authenticating.

Is there a way to do it other then just overriding the sessions controller?

**Update:**

Used the following method: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

The reason is we have some users already, and we need to allow them to login with email as well if they did not capture their mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a method in your ApplicationController (only since you don't want to override SessionsController) that will convert `params[:mobile]` to whatever format you want.

```
prepend_before_filter :format_mobile_param

def format_mobile_param
  return unless params[:mobile]
  params[:mobile] = your_formatting_method(params[:method])
end
```

This will alter the params before the call is made to `authenticate_user!` (assuming you call `authenticate_user!` in a before filter).

Comment: Thanks this worked, but decided to use another strategy rather than changing controller etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to override the SessionsController, just add a prepend_before_filter :format_mobile_param. Don't forget to scope this method to the create method of SessionsController.
Also, dont forget to add the controller routes. Hope it helps.